# Crystal Report Input Parameter Hyphen Error

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports

I have an input parameter field in my Crystal Report for PO numbers which often include '-'. However, when my users try to input a PO with that hyphen, they get an error saying "incorrect syntax near '-'". Is there a setting I need to be selecting to make this work? I'm relatively new to Crystal Reports and this one has me stumped!

Comment: You likely have some other issue going on.  I have several crystal reports in my library of reports that all use parameter fields to allow users to input values that contain hyphens, and none of my reports have any issues.  Remember, Formula Fields aren't the only objects in a report's design that can contain a formula.  There has to be something somewhere in the report that is using a formula to evaluate your parameter field in a way that throws this error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the data type of the parameter is set correctly.
For example, if the PO# is a text (string) field, set the parameter ***Type*** to '***String***' rather than '***Number***'.

Comment: It is set correctly, thank you for mentioning that though!

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you probably have a formula that is trying to convert the parameter value to a number. It chokes on the embedded hyphen.

Change the formula to use Replace({?YourParmaterName}, "-", "") instead of the raw value of the parameter.  That would remove the "-" from the parameter value and allow the conversion to a number.

Comment: We need the keep that hyphen in the PO number though, since that is a customer-facing field and it needs to look the same in our system and their system. And there are no formula fields in my report!

Comment: It's probably the Record Selection Formula. Menu choice of Report, Selection Formula, Record...
This is not about changing your PO# -- it is about making the parameter value play nicely with your formula logic.

Comment: Okay so I've found that as long as I put the PO with a hyphen in quotes, it works just fine. So it's definitely a "type" issue..

Comment: The Record Selection shows blank, is there something behind the scenes I should be looking for?